# positional/offset based replace

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I wanted to replace text from position 11 to 18 with some text xxxxxxxxxx

Ex: 0123456789**abcdeg1**23456efsgtext1234500th23sdfksbfk

in the above line my script replaces **abcdeg1**(position 11 to 18) with xxxxxxxx
for that I'm using below script
 perl -pe 's/^(.{10}).{8}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' awktest.2019 > awktest.2019masked.txt

now problem is it's replpacing in everyline even if it's empty at those positions(11 to 18)

can someone help me in adding null check to that script i wanted to replace only is captured group is not null in the below command.(how to add null check in below command)

perl -pe 's/^(.{10}).{8}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' awktest.2019 > awktest.2019masked.txt

any help is appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Please, describe what should happen when the line is less than 18 characters long. You say "even if it's empty" and "only is captured group is not null" which seem contradictory. Add an example.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the replacement had already happened in lines which you identified as null in position *11-18*, so there are at least 8 matched chars but probably not visible to you. most likely these are just white spaces. If that is the case, you can just add a positive lookahead anchor in your pattern to make sure there is at least one non-whitespaces in the next 8 chars:

```
perl -lpe 's/^(.{10})(?=.{0,7}\S).{8}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' file
```

In the added sub-pattern **`(?=.{0,7}\S)`**:

- `(?=...)` is the positive lookahead anchor which consumes no chars in matching and can serve as a condition check
- `.{0,7}\S` means 0-7 any chars(except newline) followed by a non-whitespaces `\S`. this is to make sure in the next 8 chars, there is at least one matching `\S`
- to make sure the matches contain at least one visible chars in positions *11-18*, you may change `\S` to `[^\x00-\x20]` which includes the reverse of all non-printable chars and the SPACE (`\x20`), see a table at https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html

Answer (score 0):

use class \S; no space char.

```
a=0123456789abcdeg123456efsgtext1234500th23sdfksbfk

$ echo $a| perl -pe 's/(?<=^.{10})\S{8}/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'

0123456789xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3456efsgtext1234500th23sdfksbfk
```